# Where's Anti-Aliasing in LWRP?

Tags: unity, antialiasing

In Unity 2019.2 -LWRP (lightweight render pipeline project) the default **Game Output(Quality = High) is rendering with jaggies.**

Inorder to get a clear render ,while looking for the [Anti-Aliasing option](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PostProcessing-Antialiasing.html#href=RenderTech-DeferredShading.html) it doesn't seem to be under the default location (Edit-Project settings-Quality )for LWRP projects.

Where is the Anti-Aliasing option in LWRP and is there any other way to get a clear game render?

[image]
[image]

Comment: [Here is the very first Google result for "lwrp anti-aliasing"](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1644405/how-do-i-get-antialiasing-with-the-lightweight-ren.html).

Comment: @DMGregory- A "Bing" Search for "Unity AntiAliasing LWRP" gives different results- which are not at all helpful,Should have used Google!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your project uses a scriptable render pipelines (like the LWRP one), then settings like these are no longer found in the project settings. They can now be found in the inspector of the [render pipeline asset](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.lightweight@6.9/manual/lwrp-asset.html).

When you create a new project based on the "Lightweight RP" template, then you find three of these assets under Assets/Settings. The one used by default is the one named "LWRP-HighQuality" (you can select the pipeline asset being used in the project settings under "Graphics"):

[image: Assets]

Double-click it to see its inspector. Anti-Aliasing is found under "Quality":
[image: LWRP asset inspector]

If you still don't see anti-aliasing in the game, also make sure that anti-alliasing ("MSAA") isn't deactivated on the camera game object:

[image: Camera]